# ASCII into an INT Arduino

Tags: arduino, integer, ascii

It is so that I want to send a sensor from one Arduino worth as INT via RX TX to the other Arduino. The problem is that I want to turn on an LED on the other Arduino with this value. But there the number arrives in ASCII blocks and I would like to know whether and how I can convert the number as INT.

Here is the sender's code

```
int i = 601;
int sensorValue = 0;
int input = A0;
void setup () {

Serial.begin (9600); // Begin serial communication with 9600 baud

sensorValue = analogRead (input); // here the sensor value is written into the variable "sensorValue"

Serial.println (sensorValue); // send from the variable "sensorValue" via the serial interface
}
void loop () {

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To transport an `int` in binary you have to send the bytes of the int as a byte array.

```
Serial.write((const uint8_t*) &sensorValue, sizeof(sensorValue));
```

you can receive them as

```
if (Serial.available()) {
  Serial.readBytes((uint8_t*) &sensorValue, sizeof(sensorValue));
  ...
}
```

If you want to transport the number as text and parse it on the other Arduino, you can use the Serial.parseInt() function.

```
if (Serial.available()) {
  int sensorValue = Serial.parseInt();
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your code:
The data returned from analogRead() is not ascii. It is from 0 to 1023.
The Analog To Digital converter (ADC) converts the voltage of a pin to a number. For instance 0 for 0 volts and 1023 for 5 volts.